# Is it legal for a minor who does not live in California to lie about his/her age in order to access the NRA Web site?

Tags: united-states, internet, california, minor, firearms

[The NRA's Web site currently has a screen verifying that the user is over 18](https://agegateway.nrahq.org/?s=CA&r=https%3A%2F%2Fhome.nra.org%2F) due to a California law prohibiting "communicat[ing] to those under 18 about broad categories of firearms, parts, and accessories." Is it legal for a minor who does not live in California to lie about his/her age on this page? The law does not apply to out of state minors (because they are not minors for its purposes; "“Minor” means a natural person under 18 years of age *who resides in this state*", emphasis added), but I'm not sure if that makes it okay to enter a false age.

The text of the cited Californian law may be found here:

[BUSINESS AND PROFESSIONS CODE - BPC, DIVISION 8. SPECIAL BUSINESS REGULATIONS, 18400 - 22949.80](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displayText.xhtml?lawCode=BPC&division=8.&title=&part=&chapter=39.&article=)

Comment: If they were serious they would apply that law to the movie industry.

Comment: I just saw this in the law: "This section shall not be construed to require or authorize a firearm industry member to collect or retain age information about users or subscribers of products or services offered." Doesn't that mean the NRA's page is unnecessary? Perhaps it's just meant to criticize the law, not actually comply with it?

Comment: That's a clickwrap agreement, that would be hard to be enforced anywhere... or seen as an effective age control means.

Comment: Seems the law is applied to the NRA itself, not the minor in question. Unless the minor can be done for some sort of entrapment for tricking the NRA into committing the crime of communicating with them...

Comment: It wouldn’t be lying, it would be fibbing.

Comment: @MichaelHall fib: "A lie, especially one that is more or less inconsequential." https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/fib

Comment: My point exactly!